# c sharp Programming , .net framework

Tags: c#, printing

I have some code and string i want the string to be fixed length of 15 if 
string length is less than 15 than i want to add spacing to make my string 15 character wide for printing purpose

i have tried

```
(string.format("{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}",myRow.Cells["PREMIER REG"].Value.ToString())
```

Input string was not in correct format exception thrown

```
     myGraphic.DrawString("S# | DESCRIPTION                | QTY | PRICE 
             | SUBTOTAL", myFont, Mybrash, xMargin, ySpacing);
        ySpacing += 7;
        myGraphic.DrawLine(myPen, xMargin, yMargin, 50, 0);
        ySpacing += yMargin;         
        foreach (DataGridViewRow myRow in dataGridViewBill.Rows)
        {
            int i = 1;             
            myGraphic.DrawString(
                i+ "" + 
                myRow.Cells["gvProductTitle"].Value.ToString() + 
                myRow.Cells["gvQuantity"].Value + 
                myRow.Cells["gvPrice"].Value  +
                myRow.Cells["gvTotal"].Value
                , myFont, Mybrash, xMargin, ySpacing);
            ySpacing += yMargin;
        }
```

The problem in printing `gvquantity` value is being to pulled to product column

Comment: Could you re-phrase question title? As it stated, it's unclear what's your question about.

Comment: What Should i Do To Make my string 15 character wide no matter what the original length is

Comment: i want to make this string 15 character  myRow.Cells["gvProductTitle"].Value.ToString()    no matter how much character in it if character length is greater than fifteen then must be trim to 15 or if less then 15 then the space should be added

Comment: i Think The string.padright(15) will work

Comment: I will also recommend [ask], your title is not unrealated to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
myRow.Cells["gvQuantity"].Value.ToString().PadRight(15);
```

Comment: Both Way worked well but we should care about font style also we should use mono space like font

Answer (score 0):

String formatting allows you to specify the width (and whether to left or right align) by putting a comma after the format specifier and then the field width like:

```
string.format("{0,15}", myRow.Cells["PREMIER REG"].Value.ToString());
```

See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#controlling-formatting